# laravel 5 blade template prints html as text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have `<p><strong>Some Body Lement&nbsp;Some Body Lement</strong></p>` In database. I want to print in blade as html. but it prints as text

[image]

In my blade I have

```
@foreach( $articles as $article )
    <div class="recommended-info"><h3>{{ $article['title'] }}</h3></div>
    {{ $article['body'] }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to escape the HTML, then you need to use the `{!! !!}` syntax. Example:

```
@foreach( $articles as $article )
    <div class="recommended-info"><h3>{{ $article['title'] }}</h3></div>
    {!! $article['body'] !!}
@endforeach
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Section: "Displaying Unescaped Data".

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.
>
> Note: Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the double curly brace syntax to escape any HTML entities in the content.

Comment: OP: Please be careful with this! Laravel escapes by default to prevent [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). If you allow the public to write articles, please make sure you escape the input before displaying it this way.